# Django. How to write the time to the database in UTC when using the settings 'TIME_ZONE' and 'USE_TZ = True'

Tags: python, django, datetime

There is a Django version 4.0 project. In it, in one of the tables, I use a field to save the datetime. I need the datetime stored in UTC in the database PostgreSQL.
What I did:

```
settings.py
...
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = "UTC+3"
...

models.py
class ManualMeasurements(models.Model):
    ...    
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,
                                     default=timezone.now)
    ....
```

At the same time, migration to PostgreSQL created field with time zone:

```
"timestamp" timestamptz NOT NULL
```

Ok, but according to the documentation, this is enough so that in the form of the admin panel, the time in this field is displayed in the time field specified in settings.py , and the database was written in UTC. But no. I found that the database is currently written like this: `2023-07-10 14:55:17.000 +0300`

In admin.py I'm overriding the save method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj: ManualMeasurements, form, change, debug=True):
    if obj.timestamp:
        obj.timestamp = obj.timestamp.astimezone(time_func.get_timezone('UTC'))
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

And still in the database I get the time in the current time zone with the time zone indication. What am I doing wrong and how do I get what I need?

Comment: What's the issue here? Having a timestamp with TZ stored is better than not having a TZ in there at all.

Comment: The problem is that, when getting values from DB I would like to be sure that they are received in UTC and do conversions between time zones only when I need it. And so I always have to cast to UTC when requesting data from the DB and then operate with dates

Comment: Assuming dates are in UTC sounds more error-prone than just working with them in the TZ they are, and outputting them in whatever TZ you need...

Comment: Perhaps you are right. One way or another, you will have to use the features that Django offers.